# Does writing 'DO' let me know or 'DO' confirm sound rude?

Tags: word-usage, difference, politeness

I wrote to a colleague and wanted the respondent to reconfirm back a detail. My sentence goes.

> Do confirm back if the sample used is from ___.

Does writing 'DO' sounds rude. Does it sound like I am instructing them to do something?

Comment: I can imagine this: Do confirm to me, if you would, whether the sample used etc. "confirm back" is not great. Just confirm is enough.

Comment: I would not use *do*.  I would just use *confirm*.  That being said, you are not using *confirm* correctly.  One *confirms **that***.  One does not *confirm **if***.  Check the definition in a dictionary.

Comment: To my Canadian ears, "Confirm..." sounds possibly rude, like a direct order, which is rude if it's not to a subordinate or to someone you're very familiar with. "Do confirm..." sounds more polite, like a polite request, perhaps overly polite.

Answer (score 1):

I think, in context, it does.  A more polite version might be, “Please confirm ...,” or “Please do confirm ....”  If it’s not really optional, some alternatives are, “Remember to confirm ...,” or “Be sure to confirm ....”

Comment: Note that _do_ can also be used to emphasise a polite invitation - "Do sit down." "Do let me know if you have any questions." - but if your request to your colleague was just for something to help your own work, it's better to say "Please".